# What's the neutral element for intersection types?

Tags: typescript

For a union type, `never` is the neutral element, i.e. `never | T = T`.

Another way to see it is that for a tuple of types `T=[T_1, ..., T_n]`, the union type `T_1 | ... | T_n` is given by `T[number]`. For an empty tuple `[]`, `[][number]` yields `never` being the union type of an empty set of types.

Which type is the neutral element for intersection types? I.e. which built-in type `N` yields `N & T = T` for an arbitrary type `T` and therefore is the intersection type of an empty set?

EDIT

The rational behind my question was to build a recursive helper type to intersect all types in a tuple type. See my answer below…

Comment: Intersection types in TS only really make sense for object types, and that [type for objects is `{}`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCd0BfddUSKAIRyuVgSgDI16gA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out myself:

For a union type, `type NeutralUnion<T> = never | T` is identical to `T`.

For an intersection type, `type NeutralIntersection<T> = unknown & T` is identical to `T`.

So, similar to building `type UnionOfTupleElements<T> = T[number]`, we can build:

```
type IntersectionOfTupleElements<T extends unknown[]> = 
  T extends [infer U, ...infer V] 
    ? U & IntersectionOfTupleElements<V> 
    : unknown;
```

It yields:

```
IntersectionOfTupleElements<[]> = unknown
IntersectionOfTupleElements<[T]> = T
IntersectionOfTupleElements<[T1, T2]> = T1 & T2
```

Comment: Do you want to intersect all elements in the tuple ? If yes, there is no need in recursion. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR981W)

Comment: Actually that's where I started, but the union2intersection-tricks breaks if one of the types itself is a union:  Try `TupleIntersection<[{foo: string}, {bar: string} | {baz: number}]>;` in your playground

Comment: So if element itself is a union, you want to keep it as a union right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And that's why I tried to find the neutral element of intersections to terminate the recursion :-)

Comment: Thank you for clarification, it is nice to know :)

Comment: A bit weird though that TS has two top types (any and unknown), but intersecting with any yields any.

Comment: They have added `unknown` much later than `any` for type safety

Comment: They should deprecate any.

Comment: It will be hard to migrate from JS to TS without `any`. People will complain